# Java RMI client and remote server Connection Refused to localhost

Tags: java, localhost, rmi

I am not so experienced in Java RMI. I am trying to implement simple RMI communication, but faced with the problem.

Here my RMI client

```
public class MainClientApplication {

    public static final String FILE_NAME_RMI_POLICY = "rmi.policy";
    public static final String RMI_DOMAIN = "mydomain.net";
    public static final String RMI_ENDPOINT = "/MD5Decrypter";
    public static final String PROTOCOL = "rmi://";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + FILE_NAME_RMI_POLICY);
        System.setProperty("java.security.policy", System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + FILE_NAME_RMI_POLICY);
        String remoteHost = String.format("%s%s%s", PROTOCOL, RMI_DOMAIN, RMI_ENDPOINT);
        System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
        try {
            ComputeEngine computeEngine = (ComputeEngine) Naming.lookup(remoteHost);
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new MainWindow("MD5 Decryption", computeEngine));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Communication inerface

```
public interface ComputeEngine extends Remote {
    Object executeTask(Task t) throws RemoteException;
}
```

My server

```
public class MainServer {
    public static final int PORT = 1099;
    public static final String RMI_ENDPOINT = "MD5Decrypter";
    public static final String FILE_NAME_RMI_POLICY = "rmi.policy";
    public static final String RMI_DOMAIN = "mydomain.net";
    public static final String PROTOCOL = "rmi://";

   public MainServer() {
    try {
        System.setProperty("java.security.policy", System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + FILE_NAME_RMI_POLICY);
        //System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname", RMI_IP);
        System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname", RMI_DOMAIN);
        System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
        ComputeEngine computeEngine = new ComputeEngineExecutor();
        //  Naming.rebind(String.format("%s%s:%d/%s", PROTOCOL, RMI_DOMAIN, PORT, RMI_ENDPOINT), computeEngine);
        Naming.rebind(RMI_ENDPOINT, computeEngine);
        System.out.println("Successfully started RMI Server");
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainServer mainServer = new MainServer();
    }

}
```

And `rmi.policy`

```
grant {
    permission java.net.SocketPermission "*:1024-65535", "connect, accept";
    permission java.io.FilePermission "-", "read";
    permission java.net.SocketPermission "*:80", "connect";
};
```

So I have started rmiregistry on my server `rmiregistry 1099`. And everything works well until calling remote object method.

Here are my steps

Lets consider that my domain is `mydomain.net` , I host it on my server at home with static IP.

1. Run `rmiregistry` on the server
2. Run server application on the server
3. Run client application on any PC
4. Click button to invoke remote method

So it seems that everything connects and binds successfully, because if force enter invalid domain, endpoint or refused if rmiregistry is not started - `java.rmi.ConnectException` is thrown.

But when I try to invoke any method on remote object, BTW which has been already retrieved successfully it throws a `java.rmi.ConnectException`

```
java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.1.1; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:619)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:130)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:227)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:179)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.executeTask(Unknown Source)
    at ui.MainWindow.lambda$initGui$0(MainWindow.java:49)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
```

As I can understand the problem is that it (server) forces me to connect to my localhost instead of remote.

P.S on localhost everything works perfectly (both client and server on the one PC)

Please help to solve this problem.

**EDIT**

I have forgotten to tell that I have tried to set property of `java.rmi.server.hostname`, in this case it takes a lot of time to start the server and ends with exception.

Comment: See the RMI FAQ item A.1.

Comment: Thanks for answer , I have already tried to set `java.rmi.server.hostname` but it works weirdly, it takes a lot of time to start server and connect, but still finally doesn't work - timeout.

Comment: You set it to what? You have to show us what you did. We can't see your computer. NB you have to set it *at the server JVM.*

Comment: I have updated my server code. Of course I set it at the server JVM. It seems like it freezing in infinite loop. According to the wireshark nothing special.

Comment: Well done but there are plenty of people here at SO who have tried to set it at the client and wondered why it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leaving the 127.0.0.1 issue aside, which is solved by `java.rmi.server.hostname`, your problem now is connect timeouts. This will be caused by your firewall. You need to export your remote object on a specific port, and you need to open that TCP port in your firewall.

Comment: Thank you for answer.
I have forward port `1099` from outside world (router) to the my local PC where I am running server. 
The interesting thing is that if wait for long time aprox. 5 minutes server will start, and client can connect to it (name lookup), but again it takes a lot of time, and when I try to invoke remote method it waits and than after 5 minutes or more throws timeout exception

Comment: Port 1099 is the Registry port. You need another for the remote object. Or else create the Registry within your JVM and use 1099 for both. The timeout is because the port required isn't open. You succeeded in connecting to the Registry but not to your remote object. Sounds like you also have an enormous DNS delay.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I also tried to create registry programmatically in the code, but seems to be the same situation. 
As far as I know, client and server will use random ports to communicate with each other, I don't want to open all ports in my router. Please can you provide any example how to specify communication port for remote object.

Comment: Sigh. They use random ports *unless you export the remote object on a specific port,* which I have already told you to do twice.